# Is there a way to use the TLS 1.2 protocol with the System.Net.Sockets.Socket object?

Tags: vb.net, tls1.2

I am using the System.Net.Sockets.Socket object to send and receive data.
Currently it doesn't use TLS 1.2.  Is there a way to use the TLS 1.2 protocol with the Socket object?  Or do I need to do it a totally different way?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a useful article that I used when upgrading to TLS 1.2 for a web service: [link](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/). I hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

See the SslStream classes, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx.  There is example code at that url for both server and client side operations (although the examples are in C++ and C#).

Comment: So there is no way that the Sockets class can use the TLS 1.2 protocol?  I need to change some existing code and I am a bit hesitant to do it a entirely different way.